# Problems with Ubuntu desktop 14.04.4 download - 1.5GB RAM

Tags: 14.04

Having downloaded, a window appears. It's a Roxio registration which disappears and I'm left with three black dots - that's it, no more installation action. Help!

ps Is my "weedy"  1.5GB of RAM the issue here

pps Don't think I can burn to a DVD as the drive in my 900yo HP 530 Notebook is busted

Any help/suggestions ratefully accepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded an ISO file which needs to be burnt to a DVD. As your DVD drive is faulty Roxio is hanging.

Download the ISO file and burn the DVD on a friends PC.